# Oreo: Alarm is not fired when Application is not running

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-8.0-oreo

I have relatively simple setup that should trigger an alarm at certain time of the day and show a notification to user. here is relative code,

**Setting the alarm**

```
 long inTime = /*expirationTime*/ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 10000;
 Intent startIntent = new Intent("parking.event");
 startIntent.setClass(getBaseContext(), ParkingExpirationWarmingBroadcast.class);
 PendingIntent startPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 99, startIntent, 0);


 alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                inTime,
                startPendingIntent);
```

**BroadcastReceiver registered**

```
    <receiver
      android:name=".modules.parking.ParkingExpirationWarmingBroadcast"
      android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="parking.event" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
class ParkingExpirationWarmingBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    }
}
```

The receiver is only getting triggered if app is in background. as soon as i swipe the app from multitasking, the notification is cleared and no new Alarms are triggered. I checked this setup on Android 7.0 and BroadcastReceiver is triggered regardless of app running or not.

I am aware regarding restrictions over implicit broadcasts in Android Oreo but i don't believe the intent that i have mentioned above is considered implicit.

Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general behavior of any `Android`'s version. If you force-quit an application, then its `Alarms` and `PendingIntents` are deleted as well.

You can find the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969709/android-alarmmanager-behavior-when-application-is-forced-to-close) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401447/alarmmanager-does-not-work-when-app-is-force-closed).

Comment: What i understand is that killing app from multitasking is different than force stopping it. plus, this work as expected on 7.0. alarm is triggred even if i kill app from multitasking.

Comment: @Ankit on many devices, swiping an app from `recent tasks` is the same as `force quitting` it. You may happen to be testing your app on one of those devices.

Comment: i am testing on OnePlus 3T. The default Alarm app seems to be working fine though, even if i kill it. let me find another device with Oreo.

Answer (score 0):

Force closing an app destroys its components . This is what force stop does.  It's not a bug, it is very much a feature. Follow the following thread , it has been discussed by android framework engineers .
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/anUoem0qrxU

Comment: Well, if you read the question i did not explicitly force quite the app from settings. i just removed it from recent apps(by pressing multi tasking button and swiping left/right). 
As @Marko Pacak mentioned in his answer above, some device do consider this as force quite. 

 i did a bit of testing and the issue is only with OnePlus Devices.

Comment: None of the other apps behaves as expected. calendar wont trigger events or google keep wont pop Reminders set if they aren't in recent apps.

Comment: try replacing setExact() with setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() method . Its specified in documentation that old method setExact() doesnt work while device enters doze mode and i think this is what is happening in your case . Follow this link https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html